# Minimum amount for action='append'?

Tags: python, argparse

I have an `argparse` argument that appends, and I want it to be called at least twice. (`args.option` would contain at least two lists) I know that one way would be to check it myself, but I would prefer a way to make `argparse` do it.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Do the thing')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--option', nargs=3, action='append', metavar=('A', 'B', 'C'))
args = parser.parse_args()
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that argument, each time you use a '-o' flag, it looks for 3 strings, and it puts them in a list in the output:

```
In [127]: import argparse
     ...: 
     ...: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Do the thing')
     ...: parser.add_argument('-o', '--option', nargs=3, action='append', metavar=('A', 'B', 'C'));

In [128]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-o A B C]

Do the thing

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o A B C, --option A B C

In [129]: parser.parse_args('-o 1 2 3 -o a b c'.split())
Out[129]: Namespace(option=[['1', '2', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'c']])
```

There's no mechanism in `argparse` to check the length of `args.option`.  Nor any meta-nargs to requires the double use of '-o'.

```
In [130]: parser.parse_args(''.split())
Out[130]: Namespace(option=None
In [131]: parser.parse_args('-o 1 2 3'.split())
Out[131]: Namespace(option=[['1', '2', '3']])
```

You could define 2 positionals with the same `dest`.  The parsing works ok, but the `usage` formatting has problem, raising error with both help and error messages.  I'd stick with checking `len(args.option)`.

Comment: There's no way? shame.   
As an aside, what's with your weird REPL?

Comment: I'm using `ipython` (technically the Jupter QtConsole).

Comment: On further thought, I can imagine writing a custom version of the 'append' Action class, that does complain when you use it more than 2 times.  It couldn't complain about 0 or 1 uses, since it can only complain when used.  As is typical with interactions, it is easier to test after parsing than during.